# What are the correct techniques for implementing functional client access to an asynchronous serial interface?

Tags: serial, arduino-mega

This is not a question for beginners.

I am implementing a functional interface to an asynchronous serial device connected to the Serial1 port on a mega.

To ensure clarity, I want to implement a series of functions thus:

```
    {param} CallInterface({param1},{param2},...) {
        sendRequestPacket();
        ....{await Response or timeout}....
        return Response;
     }
```

Obviously, when "awaiting Response" we are blocking the operational thread and have to allow an additional thread processor access in order to retrieve and parse the response.

On a multithreaded platform, this would be trivial to implement using semaphores and other multi-threading techniques, but on Arduino,AVR the solution is possibly less obvious, or not.

So, the question is, what is the best and most effective way to implement a pattern such as this on the Arduino platform?

Comment: `Obviously, when "awaiting Response" we are blocking the operational thread` ... actually, that is not obvious ... you could use non-blocking code

Comment: It's hard to tell what's the “best and most effective” without knowing the exact requirements of your project. I once faced a similar situation when I needed my code to be non-blocking. I then added a “callback” parameter to `CallInterface`, to which the response is to be delivered, and an `update()` method to the object implementing the interface, in order for it to catch the response and deliver it to the callback.

Comment: @jsotola can you please follow this up with an example of a non-blocking code pattern That would work on the Arduino platform?

Comment: @EdgarBonet Thanks Edgar, yes this is a similar model to Async Javascript / Node. Initial impressions are that I would need to implement a callback array in the receiver code to capture any and all potential requests for this data that need to be fulfilled when and if the response arrives. The only issue I foresee with this is that there is no "linkage" between the request and response other than the fact that the response happens soon after the request.

Comment: There is no way of linking a specific request with a specific response other than to block requests until all pending requests are fulfilled, or a timeout occurs.

Comment: one of the parameters of the call can be forwarded to the callback. or with lambdas you can capture parameters

Answer (score 0):

The typical way I handle this kind of thing is to have one "master" function that controls everything using a finite state machine in a non-blocking way.

That function *could* contain all the logic to do things, or it could be simpler and just handle the basic communication and then pass details on to a callback function that is specified in the action function call.

So the flow could be:

1. You call a function that just sets up things:

- It stores details of the request to be made
- It records the address of a "callback" function

2. You execute your "run" function repeatedly from `loop()`

- It sends the command to the target
- It receives and parses the response storing it internally somewhere
- When the response is complete it executes the callback function passing it the response

Not all of 2 would happen each iteration of `loop()`, so write it in a non-blocking way (using `.available()` etc) and only call the callback when everything is complete.

So in that way you can set up a chain of things to happen:

1. You submit request 1 with callback A.
2. Callback A submits request 2 with callback B.
3. Callback B submits request 3 with callback C.

... etc ...

As an example this is how a modem control could look:

```
Modem.command("AT+CREG?", testRegistration);
>>> send         AT+CREG?
<<< store        +CREG: 0,2
<<< store
<<< identify     OK
--- Execute testRegistration(true, "+CREG: 0,2\n\n");
```

Or maybe if it goes wrong:

```
Modem.command("AT+CROG?", testRegistration); // Oops, made a typo...
>>> send         AT+CROG?
<<< identify     ERR
--- Execute testRegistration(false, "");
```